# Evaluate the indefinite integral $\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ without trigonometric substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In order to find
$$
\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
we set $t=\arctan x$. Then $x=\tan t$ and $dt=\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$, so
$$
\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2t}}}=\int\cos tdt\\
=\sin t+C=\sin(\arctan x)+C
$$
Now, since
$$
\sin(\arctan x)=\sqrt{\frac{\tan^2(\arctan x)}{\tan^2(\arctan x)+1}}
$$
the answer is $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+C$.

**My Question**: Is there another way to find this integral without using trigonometry?

Comment: Differentiate $x^a(x^2+1)^b$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint** One method is to apply the Euler substitution,
$$\sqrt{1 + x^2} = t + x , \qquad dx = - \frac{1 + t^2}{2 t^2}\,dt ,$$
which transforms the integral to $$-4 \int \frac{t\,dt}{(1 + t^2)^2}.$$

Another is to apply the substitution
$$x = \frac{1}{u}, \qquad dx = -\frac{du}{u^2},$$ which transforms the integral to $$\int \frac{u \,du}{(1 + u^2)^{3 / 2}} .$$

Comment: Thanks @Travis Willse.

Answer (score 8):

$$\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\overset{x=\frac1y}=
-\int \frac y{(1+y^2)^{3/2}}dy=\frac1{\sqrt{1+y^2}}+C
$$

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to use power series:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n} x^n \tag{1} $$
$$\text{by differentiation and reindexing}\quad \frac{1}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}(2n+1) x^n \tag{2}$$
$$\text{by }x\mapsto -x^2\quad \frac{1}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}(2n+1)(-1)^{n} x^{2n} \tag{3}$$
$$\text{by termwise integration}\quad \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}(-1)^n x^{2n+1}\tag{4} $$
and by comparing $(4)$ and $(1)$ we have that the RHS of $(4)$ is $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $u=x^2+1$.

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int{u^{-\frac{3}{2}}(u-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}du=\frac{1}{2}\int{u^{-2}\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}du$$

Using the general formula $\int{(f(x))^nf'(x)}dx=\dfrac{(f(x))^{n+1}}{n+1}+c$ (which can be verified by differentiating the right side),

$$I=\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+c=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+c$$

Comment: setting $v=1-\frac{1}{u}$ does the job, too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use *hyperbolic trigonometry*. Set $x=\sinh t$, $x^2+1=\cosh^2 t$, $dx=\cosh t dt$, and you get:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}&=&\int\frac{\cosh t\,dt}{\cosh^3 t}\\&=&\int\frac{dt}{\cosh^2 t}\\&=&\tanh t+C\\&=&\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t}+C\\&=&\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+C\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks. The last identity is not trivial (as in the trigonometric solution). Is there more "standard" solution?

Comment: The last identity is just $\tanh t=\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x = \sqrt{\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}}$ :

$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac{dx}{\left(x^2+1\right) \sqrt{x^2+1}} \\
&= - \int \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1+y}{1-y}} \, \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2}}{\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y} + 1\right) \sqrt{\frac{1-y}{1+y} + 1}} \\
&= - \frac1{2\sqrt2} \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1-y}2} + C \\
&= \frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}} + C
\end{align*}$$